# How do I label lines in a MatLab plot?

Tags: matlab

[What my plot looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii6Gl.png)

[What the plot should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpex7.png)

The code is working like it should but im trying to get the labels to show up on each line from (1-8). Just like the picture above.

I have read a bunch of posts and tried to search Matlab but i havent been able to figure it out.

```
clc;clear;close all;
V_inf = 20;                         % freestream velocity
R = 1;                              % cylinder radius
n = 8;                              % number of panels
d_theta = 2*pi/n;                   % resolution of angles
alpha = 0;                          % angle of attack
theta = pi+pi/n:-d_theta:-pi+pi/n;  % angles of boundary points of panels
X = R*cos(theta);                   % X coordinates of boundary points of panels
Y = R*sin(theta);                   % Y coordinates of boundary points of panels

Phi =   zeros(n,1);                 % angle from Vinf to bottom of panel
beta =  zeros(n,1);                 % angle from Vinf to outward normal of panel
conX =  zeros(n,1);                 % X coordinates of control points
conY =  zeros(n,1);                 % Y coordinates of control points
S =     zeros(n,1);                 % panel length
for i = 1:n
    Phi(i) = -alpha + atan2((Y(i+1)-Y(i)),(X(i+1)-X(i)));             
    beta(i) = Phi(i)+pi/2;  
    if beta(i)>2*pi, beta(i)=beta(i)-2*pi; 
    elseif beta(i)<0, beta(i)=beta(i)+2*pi; end
    conX(i) = (X(i+1)+X(i))/2;                                          
    conY(i) = (Y(i+1)+Y(i))/2;                                          
    S(i) = sqrt((X(i+1)-X(i))^2 + (Y(i+1)-Y(i))^2);                     
end


close all
plot(R*cos(0:0.01:2*pi),R*sin(0:0.01:2*pi),'b', X,Y,'r',conX,conY,'g^'); 
axis equal; legend('Exact shape','Panel approximation','Control points')
xlabel('x, m'); ylabel('y, m'); title('Fig. 1 Panel layout (n = 8, R = 1m)');
```

Answer (score 3):

Possibly plotting the labels along the points of a circle using the `text()` function may suffice. There's some shifting of points and flipping that needs to be done to get the order you wish but otherwise it's just 8 points taken along a circle that is smaller in diameter in comparison to the octagon. An alternative would be using the green triangles as reference instead but that involves more math. As long as your octagon is expected to be symmetrical vertically and horizontally this should work alright.

[image]

```
clc;clear;close all;
V_inf = 20;                         % freestream velocity
R = 1;                              % cylinder radius
n = 8;                              % number of panels
d_theta = 2*pi/n;                   % resolution of angles
alpha = 0;                          % angle of attack
theta = pi+pi/n:-d_theta:-pi+pi/n;  % angles of boundary points of panels
X = R*cos(theta);                   % X coordinates of boundary points of panels
Y = R*sin(theta);                   % Y coordinates of boundary points of panels

Phi =   zeros(n,1);                 % angle from Vinf to bottom of panel
beta =  zeros(n,1);                 % angle from Vinf to outward normal of panel
conX =  zeros(n,1);                 % X coordinates of control points
conY =  zeros(n,1);                 % Y coordinates of control points
S =     zeros(n,1);                 % panel length
for i = 1:n
    Phi(i) = -alpha + atan2((Y(i+1)-Y(i)),(X(i+1)-X(i)));             
    beta(i) = Phi(i)+pi/2;  
    if beta(i)>2*pi, beta(i)=beta(i)-2*pi; 
    elseif beta(i)<0, beta(i)=beta(i)+2*pi; end
    conX(i) = (X(i+1)+X(i))/2;                                          
    conY(i) = (Y(i+1)+Y(i))/2;                                          
    S(i) = sqrt((X(i+1)-X(i))^2 + (Y(i+1)-Y(i))^2);                     
end


close all
plot(R*cos(0:0.01:2*pi),R*sin(0:0.01:2*pi),'b', X,Y,'r',conX,conY,'g^'); 
axis equal; legend('Exact shape','Panel approximation','Control points')
xlabel('x, m'); ylabel('y, m'); title('Fig. 1 Panel layout (n = 8, R = 1m)');

%*************************************************************************%
%ADDING LABELS BY PLOTTING LABELS ALONG CIRCLE%
%*************************************************************************%

Radius = 0.8;
Number_Of_Data_Points = 9;
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,Number_Of_Data_Points);
X_Circle = Radius*cos(theta);
X_Circle = X_Circle(1:end-1);
Y_Circle = Radius*sin(theta);
Y_Circle = Y_Circle(1:end-1);

X_Circle = flip(circshift(X_Circle,3));
Y_Circle = flip(circshift(Y_Circle,3));

for Point_Index = 1: numel(conX)
    
    X_Displacement = X_Circle(Point_Index);
    Y_Displacement = Y_Circle(Point_Index);

    text(X_Displacement,Y_Displacement,num2str(Point_Index),'HorizontalAlignment','center','fontsize',20);
end
```

---

### To Plot on Control Points:

```
%*************************************************************************%
%ADDING LABELS BY PLOTTING LABELS ALONG CONTROL POINTS%
%*************************************************************************%
for Point_Index = 1: numel(conX)
    text(conX(Point_Index),conY(Point_Index),num2str(Point_Index),'HorizontalAlignment','center','fontsize',20);
end
```

Comment: This works for 8 lines with the main radius = 1, but when the radius & number of panels are different then it dosen't work. This is the issue im having. I need it to change when my R&n values change.

Comment: @miket would simply plotting on top of the control points suffice?? That would make the task a lot easier than trying to offset the labels.

Comment: yes, that would work but idk how.

Comment: Try adding this to your original script:
`for Point_Index = 1: numel(conX)
text(conX(Point_Index),conY(Point_Index),num2str(Point_Index),'HorizontalAlignment','center','fontsize',20);
end`

Comment: how do i offset the labels from the center of the control points? I was told to use offset but matlab says the function is not found. im trying to get it to plot the labels next to the lines, not on top of them.

Comment: @miket This might take some trigonometry to figure out. Might be a little bit difficult since the offset will change from positive and negative depending on the location from the origin.